# TextInputLayout bottom line overflows text

Tags: android, android-support-design

I have this weird bug on LG G3 S with com.android.support:design:23.1.0. I don't how to fix it, can somebody help me?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that there is no appropriate solution for this bug.

I've tried to update a support design library to 23.1.1, but it didn't fix it. So I just add the `android:maxLength="120"` param to the nested EditText.

Now user can't type more then 120 chars, so the bug is just hidden, but not resolved.